# Limpiar el formulario después del envío con AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Este es mi Script para el envío de datos mediante AJAX.

Me funciona todo bien, pero los valores de mi formulario, después de enviarlo, no se borran.

¿Sabías que tengo que añadir para borrar el texto del formulario, una vez enviado?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
        var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"insertar.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    alert("agregado con exito");
                    //¿Aquí iría el borrar contenido del formulario no?

                }else{
                    alert("Fallo el server");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saludos se me ocurre que el val o value de cadas input lo regreses a "" es decir sin un valor, del modo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnguardar').click(function(){
        var datos=$('#frmajax').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"insertar.php",
            data:datos,
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    alert("agregado con exito");
                    //así le indicarías que después de tener un procesamiento exitoso limpie los inputs
                    $('#campoUno').val('');
                    $('#campoDos').val('');
                }else{
                    alert("Fallo el server");
                }
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Aclaraciones

Los inputs desde javascript o jquery los vas a invocar o por su id o por su clase como puedes notar en el ejemplo; entonces le indicas que acceda al método **val()** y le indicas que como parámetro quede sin contenido **val('')**

Ahora bien al final para devolver el focus o cursor a un campo específico pudieras probar con el método del mismo nombre mas o menos así:

```
$('#campoUno').focus()
```

Saludos espero ser de ayuda

Comment: sii, perfecto, gracias!

Comment: si lo se, pero no puedo marcarla hasta después de 8 minutos, dentro de un minuto ya se cumple :) gracias por la ayuda

Comment: te agregue un dato mas a la respuesta espero te sea útil

Answer (score 1):

Sí, en ese lugar iría el código. Para limpiar el formulario deberías agregar el siguiente código:

```
document.getElementById("frmajax").reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiete manera:

```
$(function(){
    form = $("#frmajax");
    form.submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insertar.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (r) {
                if (r == 1) {
                    alert("agregado con exito");
                    form[0].reset(); //Limpiar el formulario
                } else {
                    alert("Fallo el server");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Para que funcione debes agregar un input tipo 'submit', la línea de código que limpia el formulario está comentada.